# Django default cache

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-settings, django-cache

I'm importing and using cache as this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache.add('a','b',60)
```

I haven't defined any settings for the cache in settings.py ,then where does this cache come from and where is it stored.

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) says: "This object is equivalent to caches['default']", but what is the default ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching says:

> **Local-memory caching**
>
> This is the default cache if another is not specified in your settings
>   file

*updated dead link*

Comment: To add on to this, local memory caching is per process. So, this cache wont work for all the instances of your application. Only for the current one.

Answer (score 9):

Empirically

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.CACHES
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, [**Local-memory caching**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) is used which is **one of [django caches](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/)**.

So, because [**Local-memory caching**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) is default, you don't need to write **the code for [Local-memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching)** to **"settings.py"** as shown below unless you use **multiple local memory caches**:

```py
# "settings.py"

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```